# Some materials aren't rendered in the Blender Game Engine

Tags: game-engine, materials, opengl, append

As I described in the title, some materials aren't rendered. I'm not sure, but I think it only happens if I "copy paste" or append objects with their materials. I can solve this problem by recreating the broken materials (but this is a tedious task).

The materials are visible in textured viewport. Only when I  **start** the BGE they are invisible.

Here you can Download the .blend:

[Download](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4jwpby7ev99hurb/GE%20material%20problem.blend?dl=0)

(it is a car game. on the left is a text editor where I describe the problem again)

[image]

in this picture you can see the Material which disappears.

Thanks

[image]

Comment: Could you give us the example .blend(s) or some more precise recreation steps? Because I didn't noticed such thing myself yet.

Comment: Which object's materials are you referring too? I did not find any materials to disappear.

Comment: @Lev it's the object 'Luftauslassheck' the mats are ChromeGE and BlackPlasticGE all normals pointing outward.

Comment: Yup, I asked before the edit. Since it wasn't the normals I only thought that something that is not supported by the GE , but is only supported by the Internal renderer. But someone more capable should answer.

Answer (score 1):

I am having the same problem. Best solution I could find (more like a workarround) is to apply all the modifiers of the object which is causing trouble (in our case, it is *Luftauslassheck*).

Should you find out what is happening, please let me know. Here is [a link to my blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2i0zhvlnmc5dhc1/fridge.blend?dl=0) if you want to take a look at it. The object is *Support.Cover*, which only has the material *PlasticMaterial.002*, used in other objects as well.

Nice car model by the way